# How to find percentage of query result in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Find the percentage of departments that have a manager. Round the result to 2 decimal places.

I am able to find the result of how many departments has manager, but how will i find its percentage?

```
SELECT  department_name 
from hr_departments
where manager_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Sounds like you want some help with your test or homework? What have you tried already? Seems like you can already retrieve the departments with a manager, so finding the departments without a manager seems doable as well? And I'm hoping you can calculate the percentage next right?

Comment: That what i asked I don't know how to find the percentage of the departments with managers

Comment: Alright, MT0 explains that below. Good luck!

Comment: @HarmanjitSingh If there are 15 departments that have a manager and there are 30 departments in total, what calculation would you do to calculate the percentage of the departments with a manager of the total number of departments?

Comment: 15 / total * 100

Answer (score 1):

Since this appears to be a homework question, you want to use an aggregation function to `COUNT` the number of departments where the `manager_id IS NOT NULL` and compare that to the `COUNT` of the total number of rows in the table; then to get the value as a percentage multiply the value by 100 and then `ROUND` to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- % that have managers = (# that have managers / total # of departments) * 100

SELECT ROUND(((SELECT COUNT(department_name) 
     FROM hr_departments 
     WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL) / 
     (SELECT COUNT(department_name)
     FROM hr_departments) * 100), 2)
FROM hr_departments
```